# Libgdx Individually reference textures

Tags: libgdx

In my game I have some gold that the player can collect. My problem is I want to individually refernce textures of gold so i can take that particular instance of gold off the screen (player picked it up). How would I go about doing this as i am pretty sure you cannot do this with regular textures. Would i have to create a shape and fill it with the gold texture so I can delete that particualr gold piece? Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you confuse `Texture` (which is basically a loaded image that you can draw) with game entities. Depending on how you implement your game, you can spawn multiple bodies (Box2D), actors (Scene2D) or your simple data containers (width, height, x, y) representing each coin and draw each one on the screen using the *same* texture. Actually, that's the preferred way to handle assets: you load images once and then simply reuse them for each sprite.

I suggest looking into the following classes:

- [Sprite](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) (makes it easier to draw textures).
- [Image](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Image.html) (allows to display simple images on Scene2D stage).
- [Box2DSprite](https://bitbucket.org/dermetfan/libgdx-utils/wiki/net.dermetfan.gdx.graphics.g2d.Box2DSprite) (third party utility class that makes it easier to draw Box2D worlds).

Comment: Can i just ask do any of these classes allow me to set a reference number that is unique to each instance that i could delete them seperately?

Comment: `Image` (like any other `Actor`) allows you to use `setUserObject` to store some additional, custom data, but generally I'd just use a custom class that *wraps* one of these objects. For example, you can create a `Coin` class which extends `Sprite` (or has a `Sprite` field) and generates a unique ID in the constructor or implements `boolean isDestroyed()` method, so you can remove it (while iterating over the coins to draw them).

Comment: You can also hold them in a collection that allows fast removal given a certain ID - for example, LibGDX `IntMap<Sprite>`, which allows you to map your `Sprite` instances by their unique int IDs. You can use its `values()` method to iterate over all current sprites.